# Why do Google-tags have a picture in stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, google, tags, stack-overflow

When you look at Stackoverflow's recent tags you'll see that some have a little favicon in front of them. Conspicuously the affected tags are mostly Google products (android, google-chrome, google-drive-sdk, google-plus, ...).

Why is that?

Comment: well, aside from the illuminati thing you are thinking about, mostly because google products have an icon and the c++ language for example hasnt a offical one ( my stupid believe )

Comment: cuda, gpu, gpgpu also have 'favicons'

Comment: Do you think - for example - Apple-related tags don't have one because Apple doesn't allow to use their icons?

Comment: Microsoft also involved, see [tag:azure]. :)

Comment: @Najzero well apparently - from the answers - it seems he wasn't so wrong about that illuminati thing.

Answer (score 7):

These tags are sponsored. A lot of the Facebook and Adobe tags have this as well.

Basically, the company pays for the little icon and an ad in the tag page.

[image]

Comment: That's very smart of Stackoverflow. That's a subtle way of doing advertisement